# Explanation for projection

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to ask a question about projection matrices. Derivation of such matrices in 1D, as it happens in the book, goes through orthogonality of error vector $a^T(b-ma)=0$ or cosines law. I've tried to think about this in a following way(in 1D): 1) we take vector $a$ (on which we projecting) and $a^\bot$; 2) from this basis we construct space and locating there b vector(which we projecting); 3)taking x component; In result i get    $\begin{bmatrix}ka_1\\ka_2\end{bmatrix}$= $\begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{a^2_2+a^2_1} & 0\\0 & \frac{1}{a^2_2+a^2}\end{bmatrix}$ $\begin{bmatrix}b_1a^2_1 +a_1a_2b_2 \\a_1a_2b_1+a^2_2b_2 \end{bmatrix}$. I check this through error vector $\begin{bmatrix}a_1 & a_2\end{bmatrix}$$\begin{bmatrix}b_1-ka_1 \\b_2-ka_2 \end{bmatrix}$, and this equals 0. But when i've tried to do same procedure in 3D i never could obtain vector in a plane on which i'm projecting. I can't understand why. For example: i take $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 & 1/3\\2 & 1 & -5/3\\ 3 & 1 & 1\end{bmatrix}$  and $\begin{bmatrix}1 \\2 \\ 2\end{bmatrix}$ (as b), and i end up with $\begin{bmatrix}0.6857 \\0.2 \\ -0.25\end{bmatrix}$ (as a representation of b in this space), but when i solving $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2\\2 & 1 \\3 & 1\end{bmatrix}$$\begin{bmatrix}a \\c \end{bmatrix}$ $\begin{bmatrix}0.6857 \\0.2 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$, i got $-0.27+0.39 \ne 0 $. Could you please tell me what is wrong with my understanding of this situation? Thank you very much, sorry for long question.

Comment: Are you trying to project $(1,2,2)^T$ onto $(1,2,3)^T$ in your second example?

Comment: Hello, i'm trying to project [1,2,2] onto plane spanned by [1,2,3] and [2,1,1]

Comment: I see. I don’t understand what you’re trying to do after you’ve found the coordinates of $b$ in the alternate basis. The “error vector” is just $(1,2,2)^T-(0.6857\times(1,2,3)^T+0.2\times(2,1,1)^T)$.

Comment: I'm trying to find whether or not this new vector which i found is indeed located in this plane, if i understood correctly some combination of this two guys [1,2,3],[2,1,1] should give me this vector, but they doesn't. I probably should practice a bit in art of asking questions.

Comment: the only thing i was trying to ask is how i can find projection in 3d space without mentioning error vector or cosines, by transformations of the space alone, so i could understand it visually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re almost there. You’ve computed the coordinates $(b_1,b_2,b_3)$ of the vector being projected in the new basis $(v_1,v_2,v_3)$. Recall what these coordinates represent: they are the coefficients of the basis vectors in the linear combination $$b=b_1v_1+b_2v_2+b_3v_3\tag{*}$$ Just as you would find the projection of a vector onto the standard $x$-$y$ plane by setting its $z$-coordinate to zero, you now find the projection onto $\operatorname{span}(v_1,v_2)$ by setting $b_3=0$ in (*) to get $0.6857\times(1,2,3)^T+0.2\times(2,1,1)^T=(1.086,1.571,2.257)^T$ or, in matrix form, $$\left[\begin{array}{ccr}1&2&\frac13\\2&1&-\frac53\\3&1&1\end{array}\right]\begin{bmatrix}0.6857\\0.2\\0\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1&2\\2&1\\3&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}0.6857\\0.2\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1.086\\1.571\\2.257\end{bmatrix}.$$ This vector is clearly on the plane because of the way it was constructed, but if you want to double-check by solving $$\begin{bmatrix}1&2\\2&1\\3&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1.086\\1.571\\2.257\end{bmatrix}$$ watch out for rounding errors that can throw this off.